# How to update a Pandas datafrae column based on another column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df from an Excel file like this one:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | aaa | xxx |
| bb | bb | xxx |
| ccc | 123 | yyy |
| ddd sss | NA - Not Listed | xxx |
| ddd sss | 34 | xxx |

As you can see, col1 last row's value is "ddd sss".

I'm trying to update "**col2**" value with only "ddd" from "**col1**" value, if "**col3**" == "xxx".

In another words, replace every "NA" from col2 by the first string from col1 only if col3 == "xxx"

Get the "ddd" from the "ddd sss" is not a problem, at least that is working :)

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask and fill with a section of string required.

```
#df['col2']=df.col3.mask(df.col3.eq('xxx'),df.col1.str.split('\s').str[0]) initial answer before edit changes
```

Solution

```
df['col2']=df.col2.mask(df.col3.eq('xxx')&df.col2.str.contains('NA - Not Listed'),df.col1.str.split('\s').str[0])
```

outcome

```
      col1 col2 col3
0      aaa  aaa  xxx
1       bb   bb  xxx
2      ccc  123  yyy
3  ddd sss  ddd  xxx
4  ddd sss   34  xxx
```

Comment: Thank you very much wwnde, I'm working on user suggestion. the only thing is that maybe I did something wrong as it is changing all col2 values, it's ignoring the 'xxx' selection.

Comment: It should work. What do you mean. Retested and all good.

Comment: Could you try this `df['col2']=df.col3.mask((df.col3.eq('xxx')&df.col2.isna()),df.col1.str.split('\s').str[0])` and let me know

Comment: wwnde I poorly choose the value of my example, my "NA" is not related to nan, the full string is "NA - Not Listed".

I'll review what I did, as I mentioned probably is my mistake. I just can't do it right now but I'll let you know.

Thanks again !!

Comment: Will eidt that for you and try change the answer

Comment: Please see my edits. Happy to help further

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer would to use a different delimiter, but if you cannot do that:

```
df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'])
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

You could also define a function that goes through each row with `.apply(axis = 1)`, check for the split and the `nan` and replace accordingly for a more generic method.

Comment: Thanks WolVes for your time to try to help me! The only thing is that I should update 'col2' only when 'col3' contains a specific value, like the 'xxx' in my example

Answer (score 2):

use numpy.where:

```
df['col2'] = np.where((df['col3'] == 'xxx') & (df['col2'].isna()),
                      df['col1'].str[:3], df['col2']) # str[:3] assumes that you only want the first three characters


      col1 col2 col3
0      aaa  aaa  xxx
1       bb   bb  xxx
2      ccc  123  yyy
3  ddd sss  ddd  xxx
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll try it. Actually the position of the first space in the col1 is variable, but that isn't a problem.